# Javascript error when calling a function in initialize()

Tags: javascript

I have a page for carpools.  I made some changes to the function that calls initialize and now getting errors.  Here is the page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_carpool.php?hike_id=180

What is the correct way to have the second argument when I call the initialize function?  I think some JavaScript errors are coming from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using your quotes right:

```
onload="initialize( 180 , "Hike_Carpool" ); placeHikeStartMarker( 180 );  placeCarpoolPassengersMarkers( 180 ); placeCarpoolDriversMarkers( 180 );"
```

Should be:

```
onload="initialize( 180 , 'Hike_Carpool' ); placeHikeStartMarker( 180 );  placeCarpoolPassengersMarkers( 180 ); placeCarpoolDriversMarkers( 180 );"
```

Notice the single-quotes on the Hike_Carpool parameter.

This is because of the double-quoted onload element attribute. The double-quotes on the initialize function cannot be parsed correctly, creating a syntax error.

Comment: @Genadinik - Sure, no problem. Happens to the best of us. :)